# jQuery / Javascript execution order?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to exactly figure out the execution order of what is going on here. I'm using jquery to retrieve new data, and I get occasional irregularities. How I have its current work flow order should be something like this:

1. Onload - get() function (retrieves data for both divs)
2. The move() function is activated via a button
3. move.php has the mysql_query update action
4. Reload the div with the updated database information.

---

```
function get(varpass) {
    varpass = typeof(varpass) != 'undefined' ? varpass : "all";
    var j = "<?=$_SESSION['username']?>";
    if (varpass == "all" || varpass == "left") {
        $('#left').hide();
        $.get('data.php', {
            name: j,
            p: varpass
        }, function (output) {
            $('#left').html(output).fadeIn(250);
        });
    }
    if (varpass == "all" || varpass == "main") {
        $('#main').hide();
        $.get('main.php', {
            name: j,
            p: varpass
        }, function (output) {
            $('#main').html(output).fadeIn(250);
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    get("all");
});
function move(p) {
    var j = "<?=$_SESSION['username']?>";
    $.get('move.php', {
        name: j,
        p: p
    }, function (output) {
        $('#debug').html(output).fadeIn(1);
    });
    $('#main').hide();
    get("main");
}
```

I find that on occasion the div will retrieve information before the move.php mysql_query has been completed. How can control the order of execution better? I want the information to finish being updated before it calls to retrieve the data from the database again.

Thanks

Comment: For future reference, please format your code properly for readability :)

Comment: Do you mean you want the repeat button clicks to not call the move function until it has completed?

Comment: @Peter: I mean that once the move button has been clicked it should: A. Update sql with adjusted value, B. Retrieve information from database (presumable the new data just changed. I find that it will retrieve the data but it hasn't actually updated yet. I guess I'm looking for a way to force an execution order. Function move() should call the php page that evaluates how it should change and then updates the database, then get("main") will retrieve the new data into the div. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the execution order is working exactly as you expect, except for in the following snippet:

```
function move(p) {
    var j = "<?=$_SESSION['username']?>";
    $.get('move.php', {
        name: j,
        p: p
    }, function (output) {
        $('#debug').html(output).fadeIn(1);
    });
    $('#main').hide();
    get("main");  //this can/will happen before `move.php` completes
}
```

If you want the `get("main");` to not happen until after your call to `move.php` completes, then you might have better luck with something like:

```
function move(p) {
    var j = "<?=$_SESSION['username']?>";
    $.get('move.php', {
        name: j,
        p: p
    }, function (output) {
        $('#debug').html(output).fadeIn(1);
        get("main");  //this won't happen until after `move.php` completes
    });
    $('#main').hide();
}
```

By moving the `get("main");` to the response callback/handler, you can ensure that it will not be executed until after your other request has returned its response.

Comment: I see what you mean, @aroth. Excellent explanation. Many thanks.